# Is there an OR statement for jQuery? Not looking for AND statement

Tags: jquery

I have tried using multiple selectors as shown below but that is unusable in my case. Or is the only way to do it is the long and tedious way, typing each one individually?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#name,#DOB,#email,#nirc,#mobileno,#haddrs").blur(function(){
    if (!$.trim($("#name,#DOB,#email,#nirc,#mobileno,#haddrs").val())){
    $(this).addClass("error");
    } else {
        $(this).removeClass("error");
    }
});
});
```

Comment: `,` is the *or* selector.  But `.val()` will only return the value from the first one.  Exactly which part are you having difficulty with?  The selector or the .val()?

Comment: @freedomn-m Ohh, now I get why there was a problem. Then my question would be, how to have `,` and `.val()` work together.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your requirement, you can use `this` to indicate the current input and highlight just that input, or you can use `.filter` to find all of them that are empty.

You can also use .toggleClass with a boolean overload, which is the equivalent of your if/else.

Use `this` for just the current input:

```js
$("#name,#DOB,#email,#nirc,#mobileno,#haddrs").blur(function(){
   $(this).toggleClass("error", !$.trim($(this).val()))
});
```

```css
.error { background-color: pink; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id='name'>
<input id='DOB' value='today'>
<input id='email'>
```

Use `.filter` to find all empty inputs.  I've added `ids=".."` for reuse.

```js
var ids = "#name,#DOB,#email,#nirc,#mobileno,#haddrs"
$(ids).blur(function() {
  $(ids)
    .removeClass("error")
    .filter(function() {
      $(this).toggleClass("error", !$.trim($(this).val()))
    })
});
```

```css
.error {
  background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id='name'>
<input id='DOB' value='today'>
<input id='email'>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could set up an array of these classes and join them using comma as a delimeter:

```
var classes = ["#name","#DOB","#email","#nirc","#mobileno","#haddrs"];
var selector = classes.join(', ');

$(selector).blur(function(){...
```